# CSS focal point for video?

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

I am coming across a problem with a video I have in that fills that background of a div.
At a certain point the video when scaling is not tall enough. I would like to use something like css focal point but I cannot get it to work for . Does anyone know a good work around or if in fact focal point would work for video?

Thanks very much!

- M

Comment: What is "css focal point"?

Comment: @Diodeus: https://github.com/adamdbradley/focal-point#readme

Comment: Right thats what I was using. Sorry I referred to it incorrectly.